# Animation changes the position of div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well I've implementes some `divs` and when I start the page I want them animate, they do, but the problem is that sometimes one div overlaps another one then I see a blank space... How could I avoid this? I'm doing this :

This is how I change the divs :

```
function swap(d1, d2){
var topaux, leftaux;
topaux = d1.css("top");
leftaux = d1.css("left");
    d1.animate({
        top: d2.css("top"),
        left: d2.css("left"),
    }, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
    d2.animate({
        top: topaux,
        left: leftaux,
    }, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
}
```

This is how I'm trying to do it now, but after try this, I didn't have any animation so I had this code and it worked I mean no overlaps between div's....

```
    d1.css("top", d2.css("top"));
    d1.css("left", d2.css("left"));
    d2.css("top", topaux);
    d2.css("left", leftaux);
```

I call this function (swap) when I'm shuffling the divs as follows :

```
function swapdivs(){
var i,r, c, d1, d2;
for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    r = Math.floor((Math.random() * rows) + 1);
    c = Math.floor((Math.random() * columns) + 1);
    d1= $("#r"+r+"c"+c);
    r = Math.floor((Math.random() * rows) + 1);
    c=Math.floor((Math.random() * columns) + 1);
    d2 = $("#r"+r+"c"+c);
    swap(d1,d2);
}
}
```

This is the [`jfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/2wduo7mp/3/)
What I'm missing?

Comment: well, i guess it is not a javascript issue, but CSS. Can you reproduce this scenario maybe in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @pumpkinzzz how do I add the js? I remove the <script> src...</script?

Comment: I need to add 2 scripts : <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/puzzle.js"></script>

Comment: How do I add those on jsfiddle?

Comment: @pumpkinzzz I created the jfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now i see the problem.

In your *barrejarPeces* function you're scrambling randomly all elements multiple times (100)

```
for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
```

In the *interanvipeces* function you try to switch the position of 2 different elements with an animation of **1000ms**, calculating their css attributes **top** and **left**

Well, the problem is when one (or both) elements are already switching position (since the *barrejarPeces* function will scramble 100 times without waiting any animation to finish), top and left values won't be correct.

So there are 2 possible solutions:

1. Don't use animation delay (try to set to 0 instead of 1000 in your fiddle and you'll see it works)
2. Scramble all elements **just** **once** (see my [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/2wduo7mp/5/), where i changed some logic)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I ended up adding this : peça1.css("top", peça2.css("top"));
        peça1.css("left", peça2.css("left"));
        peça2.css("top", topaux);
        peça2.css("left", leftaux); below the animation and it works always

Comment: I'll study your answer too, and if you can explain why it works it I add the code that works without the animation just below the animation and doesn't show blank space I'll be glad :)